# Set specific image to all the three views in bulk upload in magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I have nearly 50k images to be uploaded in my site. I have successfully created the excel. for testing i have uploaded only one product, which has three images. so i have filled the image link in all the required columns.
Part of the excel mentioned below.

*images folder is in import folder

```
sku       image               small_image          thumbnail
EXPRO1    /images/first.jpeg  /images/first.jpeg   /images/first.jpeg
          /images/second.jpeg /images/second.jpeg  /images/second.jpeg
          /images/third.jpeg  /images/third.jpeg   /images/third.jpeg
```

In this i have three images. first.jpeg is the one i need to come in all the three views. If i have upload this excel, magento taking the last image for all the three views and it sets 1,2,3 as sort order to first.jpeg,second.jpeg,third.jpeg respectively.

How do i specifically specify which one has to come for which view in excel. I can do this manually from admin panel. But i can not afford to do that for all the products.

So please provide some solution which i can not able to find it. Sorry for my english. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Magmi uploader for this,

In your sheet you will specify like :

sku |   image  |  small_image  |  thumbnail |  media_gallery

123 |  a.png    |  a.png  | a.png   |   a.png;b.png;c.png

In magmi, it will assign the a.png image as thumbnail and small images on whole store while it will add a.png,b.png & c.png as other images on its product page.

Prerequities. you need to store all the above images in media/import folder first

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in default is there any option to get what need??? ...

Answer (score 0):

Please add "**_media_position**" column and insert images possion value in this column.